# How to configure JMeter to read data from Sharepoint excel?

Tags: sharepoint, jmeter, test-data

I would like to shift from using a CSV data set to accessing my test data directly from an online spreadsheet hosted on Sharepoint.

Is this possible in JMeter?

Expected Result:
Successfully retrieve test data directly from an online Excel spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any existing JMeter configuration elements or plugins which are capable of reading the file from Sharepoint for parameterization.

What I can suggest is downloading the file beforehand somewhere in [setUp Thread Group](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/thread-group-jmeter) via [Save Responses to a file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Save_Responses_to_a_file) listener, this way you will be able to use "normal" [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) in main Thread Group